# Crystal Reports 2008 Command text with parameters

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a query that runs correctly from SQL Developer but bombs when attempting to use it as a command-text query with parameters in Crystal Reports 2008.

### The Query (hard-coded dates; runs correctly as Oracle Query and CR 2008 Command Text)

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT PERSON.DISPLAYNAME AS NAME
               , LABOR.LA20       AS LABORRECEMPLOYEENUM
               , LABOR.LABORCODE  AS PERSONLABORCODE
        FROM   LABOR
               LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON
                 ON ( LABOR.LABORCODE = PERSON.PERSONID )
        WHERE  LABOR.LA20 IS NOT NULL
               AND LABOR.ACTIVE = 1
               AND PERSON.DISPLAYNAME IS NOT NULL
               AND LOWER(PERSON.DISPLAYNAME) NOT LIKE '%kimball%'
               AND LOWER(PERSON.DISPLAYNAME) NOT LIKE '%electrico%'
               AND LOWER(PERSON.DISPLAYNAME) NOT LIKE '%misc labor cost adj%'
               AND LOWER(PERSON.DISPLAYNAME) NOT LIKE '%brossoit'
               AND LOWER(PERSON.DISPLAYNAME) NOT LIKE '%brossiot')PERSONINFO
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                        FROM   LABTRANS
                        WHERE  LABTRANS.STARTDATE BETWEEN to_date('03/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('04/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) REDUCEDLABORRANGE
         ON ( PERSONINFO.PERSONLABORCODE = REDUCEDLABORRANGE.LABORCODE )
WHERE  REDUCEDLABORRANGE.LABORCODE IS NULL;
```

### What I'd like to do

Replace the hard-coded values:

```
WHERE  LABTRANS.STARTDATE BETWEEN to_date('03/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('04/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

With Crystal Reports parameters in command text.

### What I've tried (and errors)

```
WHERE  LABTRANS.STARTDATE BETWEEN to_date({?BeginDate}, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date({?EndDate}, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Yields the error: A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected [Database Vendor Code: 1858]

```
WHERE  LABTRANS.STARTDATE BETWEEN to_date('{?BeginDate}', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('{?EndDate}', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Yields the error: Missing Right Parenthesis [Database Vendor Code 907]

### Potential Keys to the solution

- I can't figure out what Crystal is actually sticking into the parameter values, or how they're passed on to the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And of course, soon after I post, I find the answer.

I realize, I wasn't trusting Crystal to put the dates in the proper format ahead of time (usually, not trusting Crystal Reports is the correct choice).

The following worked:

```
WHERE  LABTRANS.STARTDATE BETWEEN {?BeginDate} AND {?EndDate}
```

No need to additionally format the date, as they are already in the proper format coming out of Crystal into Oracle.

Comment: I had the same issue with Crystal Reports 2011.  I have a different date format or procedure that has to be run for almost every tool that I interact with Oracle.  Aqua Data Studio I can use '31-Jul-11' for a date format, that doesn't work with Crystal.  Crystal you let the parameters go like above.  In .Net using ODP.Net I almost always have to use the to_date method.

Comment: i am having similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968009/oracle-to-date-function-issue-in-crystal-report-for-vs2010