# Oracle TO_DATE function issue in Crystal Report for VS2010

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am having problem running following query in Crystal Report VS2010 command text. It runs fine in Oracle 10g.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_ts
WHERE PROJECTCODE = 2274
AND LOGDATE >= TO_DATE('01/08/2011','dd/mm/yyyy')
AND LOGDATE <= TO_DATE('31/08/2011','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I have tried using BETWEEN function but i am getting this same error message:

[image]

I think its something to do with `TO_DATE` function?

Comment: What is the datatype of `LOGDATE`? You can't be getting ORA-01858 from the TO_DATE calls since your string literals are perfectly matched with the date formats. Unless, of course, the query you've shown here is different from the one actually being run on your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make a guess here and assert that the error arises because the date format you specified in your code block (`'dd/mm/yyyy'`) does not exactly match what is specified in your database.

In other words, if Oracle is expecting the date in a standard format of `'DD-MON-YY'` since you are using the function as TO_DATE(some_date, `'dd/mm/yyyy'`) you are seeing this error. The "non-numeric" value would be the month name.

Comment: Should i use ('30-AUG-2011','DD-MON-YY') or ('30/08/2011','DD-MON-YY')

Comment: I think you should try the first one.

Comment: got same error message with the first one 'non numeric key' and second one gives error 'not a valid month'