# Pass Crystal parameter from main report to command object

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I find lots of info about passing parameter into subreport, but nothing about passing it from main report into command object in main report.  ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611919/crystal-reports-2008-command-text-with-parameters) is the closest I could find.)

The command object received from the vendor (names changed to reduce length) contains

```
left join LOC L on L.ID = P.Loc_ID
```

We add parameter "Area" to the main report.  {?Area} does what we expect in formulas, but it won't work in a record selection because it can't be matched to anything coming out of the command object.  If I replace table LOC in the cited line as

```
left join **(select * from LOC where A = {?Area})** L on L.ID = P.Loc_ID
```

then SQL Server complains of "syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error" [sic]

If I create the parameter **in the command object editor** (even though it already exists outside), then the whole Crystal IDE crashes!

The command object already has parameters that it magically gets from the main report.  Must I remove it from the main report (proctalgia) before adding it to the command object?  I can't find anything on any menus to link the two parameters together, like I can for a subreport.

Version 2008, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an SQL command, don't create the parameters in the main report.  The window where you put your SQL has a section called Parameter List.  Create all your parameters relating to the query there and it will be transfered to the main report.

In your coding you have {?Area}, create a parameter with the name Area.

I found a video demonstrating it.  It's an old version of Crystal Reports but still works the same.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHNHsIUbcn8

Comment: Thank you.  One extra point.  If the same parameter is already on the main report, delete it before putting it in the command object.

Answer (score 0):

I found creating the command object and the parameter FIRST is the key.  The parameter (say it is InstNo), is then created in the subreport.  You can then use "Change SubReport Links" (right click on the subreport), and select that parameter as the parameter to link to.  So basically do it backwards, create the command object first, then link it back to the main report.  For whatever reason if you do it the other way it does not work (even if the name is the same).  Just my experience.