# SQL Syntax error from query in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a query which I wrote in SQL and passed on to a Crystal Reports report.

The query works just fine and shows the information that is expected.

The problem is that everytime i try to open the report, i'm presented with a Syntax Error.

[image: SyntaxError]

```
    select funcionarios.identidade, funcionarios.numero, funcionarios.nome, CodigosAusencia.Codigo,CodigosAusencia.Descricao, Ausencias.Data,
CASE
WHEN Ausencias.Duracaoini = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and Ausencias.DuracaoFim = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' Then '08:00'

ELSE
CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATEDIFF(second,Ausencias.Duracaoini, ausencias.Duracaofim)/3600) ,':',  CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(DATEDIFF(second,Ausencias.Duracaoini, ausencias.Duracaofim)%3600) /60)) END AS Duração

From funcionarios



INNER JOIN Ausencias on funcionarios.idfuncionario = ausencias.idfuncionario
INNER JOIN CodigosAusencia on Ausencias.IDCodigoAusencia = codigosAusencia.IDCodigoAusencia
INNER JOIN Alteracoes on Ausencias.idfuncionario = alteracoes.IDfuncionario

where ausencias.Data between {?DataInicio} and {?DataFim}


Group by CodigosAusencia.Codigo, funcionarios.identidade, funcionarios.numero,
funcionarios.idfuncionario, funcionarios.nome, codigosAusencia.IDCodigoAusencia, 
CodigosAusencia.Descricao, Ausencias.Data, ausencias.DuracaoFim, ausencias.DuracaoIni, 
alteracoes.idfuncionario

Order by Funcionarios.nome
```

The error when opening the report comes from using the parameters in the query {?DataInicio} and {?DataFim} which I mandatorily need to use so my application can grab the dates for the report.

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: I see the GROUP BY, but are any set functions used?

Comment: There are no set functions since i don't need to use them in this query, but if I don't use a GROUP BY clause the query will return an error.

Comment: From the error message it looks like CR is not replacing the parameters before sending the query. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145054/pass-crystal-parameter-from-main-report-to-command-object and check if you defined them properly. (If necessary, replace the params with values and see if it works then, to narrow down the problem.)

Comment: If I change the parameters for date values, it all works fine, but obviously will only show me the dates I forced in the query. Can't figure out what is wrong, considering I have looked up similar reports, with the parameters in the query and they all work fine.